# tiny_tds failed at the second execute

Tags: sql-server, ruby, windows, tiny-tds

Today, tiny_tds suddenly does not accept more than one `execute` and returns:

```
C:\>ruby test_use.rb
one
two
C:/test_use.rb:15:in `execute': Attempt to initiate a new Adaptive Server operation with results pending (TinyTds::Error)
    from C:/test_use.rb:15
```

The code is simply as three `USE`s:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'yaml'
require 'fastercsv'
require 'tiny_tds'
require 'iconv'

CONFIG = YAML.load_file("config.yml")

client = TinyTds::Client.new(:username => CONFIG["db"]["username"], :password => CONFIG["db"]["password"], 
  :host => CONFIG["db"]["server"], :database => CONFIG["db"]["database"])

puts "one"
client.execute("USE DATAFEED")
puts "two"
client.execute("USE DATAFEED")
puts "three"
client.execute("USE DATAFEED")
```

Any clue what is the problem? I tried rebooting the Windows machine already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to terminate the execute with a `do`:

`Client.execute("...").do`

Comment: Be careful with that syntax.  If your trying todo `results = client.execute("...").do` you'll get the number of effected rows and not the results.  I've been doing `results = client.execute("...")` then call client.do later.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of how I do it.

```
results = $regcenter_db.execute("select top 10 * from events")
event_ids = results.collect { |i| i["event_id"] }
results.do
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation for TinyTds](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds) on GitHub:

It is important that you either return the data from the query, most likely with the #each method, **or that you cancel the results before asking the client to execute another SQL batch**. Failing to do so will yield an error.

To cancel the query, use the `cancel` method:

```
client.execute("USE DATAFEED").cancel
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `do` OR `cancel`. If you are doing something like getting a partial results, and you are not interested in execute the `do` method you can call `cancel` to abort the query.